# SAS Sorting within group

Tags: sorting, group-by, sas

I would like to try and sort this data by descending number of events and from latest date, grouped by ID

I have tried proc sql;

```
    proc sql; 
    create table new as
    select *
    from old
    group by ID
    order by events desc, date desc;
    quit;
```

The result I currently get is

```
    ID  Date    Events
    1   09/10/2015  3
    1   27/06/2014  3
    1   03/01/2014  3
    2   09/11/2015  2
    3   01/01/2015  2
    2   16/10/2014  2
    3   08/12/2013  2
    4   08/10/2015  1
    5   09/11/2014  1
    6   02/02/2013  1
```

Although the dates and events are sorted descending. Those IDs with multiple events are no longer grouped.

Would it be possible to achieve the below in fewer steps?

```
    ID  Date    Events
    1   09/10/2015  3
    1   27/06/2014  3
    1   03/01/2014  3
    3   01/01/2015  2
    3   08/12/2013  2
    2   09/11/2015  2
    2   16/10/2014  2
    4   08/10/2015  1
    5   09/11/2014  1
    6   02/02/2013  1
```

Thanks

Comment: Can you explain what you're trying to do here?

Comment: You need to more clearly enunciate what your rule is for sorting IDs within events.  It's not clear to me exactly why `id=3` should come before `id=2`.

Comment: Apologies for not being clear. I am looking to sort descending by number of events then by latest date. I want to also have these grouped by ID.

Comment: The issue is that although with the proc sql I can sort by  latest date and number events,  those IDs with multiple events are no longer grouped.

Answer (score 0):

It looks to me like you're trying to sort by descending event, then by either the  earliest or latest date (I can't tell which one from your explanation), also descending, and then by id. In your proc sql query, you could try calculating the min or max of the Date variable, grouped by event and id, and then sort the result by descending event, the descending min/max of the date, and id.

Comment: Thanks for attempting to answer my poorly constructed question. I will incorporate your suggestion and see if i get what i'm trying to achieve